# Dynamically generate the Time and Decimal point format for audio in html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have created a very simple audio player that plays a small mp3 file.

[image]

It works and functions has accepted but I would like to make the generation of the current Time of the audio more dynamic in that it generates both decimal and minute position placements (if needed) during the audio playback.

currently I have a function that converts an audio.mp3 current time into minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

```
this.format = function () {
    let secsCal = Math.floor(this.audio.currentTime % 60);
    let minsCal = Math.floor(this.audio.currentTime / 60);
    let millsCal = this.audio.currentTime % 60;

    let secs = ('0' + secsCal).substr(-2);
    let mins = ('0' + minsCal).substr(-2);
    let mills = ('0' + millsCal).substr(4, 2);




    document.getElementById('start-time').innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs + '.' + mills;
};
```

Now this does work for me however it is not the best solution since the time will show you the minute value even though this particular example is not a minute long. So ideally we would only want to display mins and secs if the audio warrants them.

[image]

what I am trying to achieve is:

1. Only display the decimal point if the audio is longer than a second
2. Only display the `:` if the audio sample is actually longer than a minute.

I have been searching for a solution, If anyone can help that would be most helpful

please find below my example

**[Audio HTML5 example](https://jsfiddle.net/w9914420/d4vqo2ue/30/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After a bit of soul searching, the answer to the question was relatively straight forward here is the code that makes the changes.

```
   // only display 00:00.00 formats if the mp3 requires it

   if (minutes === 0 ) {
   minResult = '\u00a0';
   } else {
   minResult = minutes + ':';
   }
   if (seconds === 0 ) {
   secResult = '\u00a0';
   } else {
   secResult = seconds + '.';
   }
   if (millisecondsCal === 0 ) {
   millResult = '\u00a0';
   } else {
   millResult = milliseconds;
   }

   // append value to dom
   document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = minResult + secResult + millResult;
```

So how this works is by first checking that we do not have any values that equate to 0, because if we do, then we don't want to display the corresponding time format, otherwise show us.

Obviously this is more of a UI request that just gives the impression that the player knows how long the track is and only displays secs and mins accordingly.

This method is placed in the duration methods. see below for further details.

```js
const audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
audio.setAttribute("id", "audio");
audio.src = "http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html/music.wav";
audio.controls = true;
audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  document.getElementById("duration").style.color = "#bdbdbd";
  document.getElementById("start-time").style.color = "white";
  
  
  
  
  // buttons
  document.getElementById("pButton").addEventListener("click", function (){
  
   // Toggle audio play
  audio[audio.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  
  });

  // Convert duration into HH:MM:SS
  duration(audio.duration);
  
};





// function converts audio.duration to SS:mm format
function duration(time) {
  var minutes = parseInt(time / 60, 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(time % 60);
  var millisecondsCal = time % 60;
  var milliseconds = ("0" + millisecondsCal).substr(4, 2);
  
  console.log(seconds);
  
  // create empty vars to store values
  var minResult = '';
  var secResult = '';
  var millResult = '';
  
   // only display 00:00.00 formats if the mp3 requires it
  if (minutes === 0 ) {
  minResult = '\u00a0';
  } else {
   minResult = minutes + ':';
  }
   if (seconds === 0 ) {
  secResult = '\u00a0';
  } else {
   secResult = seconds + '.';
  }
   if (millisecondsCal === 0 ) {
  millResult = '\u00a0';
  } else {
   millResult = milliseconds;
  }

  // append value to dom
  document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = minResult + secResult + millResult;
}

// convert audio.currentTime to SS:mm format
function format() {
  var secsCal = Math.floor(audio.currentTime % 60);
  var minsCal = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
  var millsCal = audio.currentTime % 60;
  

  var secs = ("0" + secsCal).substr(-2);
  var mins = ("0" + minsCal).substr(-2);
  var mills = ("0" + millsCal).substr(4, 2);
  
  // create empty vars to store values
  var minResult = '';
  var secResult = '';
  var millResult = '';
  
  // only display 00:00.00 formats if the mp3 requires it
  if (millsCal === 0 ) {
        millResult = '\u00a0';
    } else {
        millResult = mills;
    }

    // else if
    if (audio.currentTime < 1 ) {
        secResult = '\u00a0';
    } else {
        secResult = secs + '.';
    }

    if (minsCal === 0 ) {
        minResult = '\u00a0';
    } else {
        minResult = mins + ':';
    }

  document.getElementById("start-time").innerHTML = minResult + secResult + millResult;
}

var update = function () {
  
  format();
  
}


audio.onplay = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(audio.onplay);
  update();
  };
  
  audio.onpause = function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(audio.onplay);
  };
```

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
}

#pButton{
 
  background-color: #424242;
  border: 2px solid #bdbdbd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color:  #bdbdbd;
  float:left;
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding:20px;
}

#duration,
#start-time{ 
     padding: 20px;
     float: left;
}

.time {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
 
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
  <button id=pButton>Play</button>
  <p id="start-time" class="time"></p>
 <p id="duration" class="time">00:00</p>
```